# Hide a CCK fieldgroup using #states in hook_form_alter()?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a custom module, and I am trying to hide a CCK fieldgroup using "#states" when a certain item is selected in a drop-down select list.

I have tried using states from within hook_form_alter(), like so:

```
$form['group_mygroup']['#states']['invisible'] = array(
  ':input[name="field_trigger[' . LANGUAGE_NONE. ']"]' => array( 'value' => 'hide' ),
);
```

This doesn't seem to do anything.

I have looked at changing the weight of my module as per various sites like http://proofgroup.com/blog/2008/dec/modifying_cck_fieldgroups_hook_form_alter.

but still to no avail. I can hide all the form elements within the fieldgroup using states but not the field group itself. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: For future viewers: [@andriy-malish' answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/34667/52651) is the correct one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter.
 */
function mymodule_field_group_build_pre_render_alter(&$element) {
  if (isset($element['#form_id'])) {
    if ($element['#form_id'] == 'mynodetype_node_form') {
      $element['group_myfieldgroup']['#states'] = array(
        'visible' => array(
          ':input[name="field_myfield[und]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
        )
      );
      $element['group_myfieldgroup']['#id'] = 'group_myfieldgroup';
    }
  }
}
```

I use this hook to hide my field group. It's visible only if the checkbox `field_myfield` is checked.

To explore `$element` variable in this hook I used

```
die('<pre>'.print_r($element, 1).'</pre>');
```

instead of `dpm()`.

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Fieldgroups aren't defined in the root of `$form`. It seems you should use not `$form['group_mygroup']`, but `$form['#fieldgroups']['group_mygroup']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [example module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) to see how they [hide fieldsets](http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/form_example/form_example_states.inc). Based on that I think your code should be:

```
$form['group_mygroup']['#states'] = array(
  'invisible' => array(
    ':input[name="field_trigger"]' => array('value' => 'hide'),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Though that's the same as my code only declared slightly different. I can hide fieldsets if I declare the form and fieldset using the FAPI. My issue is that it doesn't work with CCK field groups within hook_form_alter().